# Block IE 8 and below

Tags: html, apache

Before writing some perl to take care of this, I was wondering if there was another way of blocking Internet Explorer 8 and older form viewing my website.  I would like to still allow Internet Explorer 9 and newer however.  Any ideas are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Don't do this! I get not wanting to support earlier browsers, but the way to go here is to, say, display a message to those users recommending that they upgrade. If I as a customer am blocked from using your site, I'm not going to upgrade for you. I'm going to leave.

Comment: What kind of a block would you like? Something that blocked rendering of content or something that prevented access to the content entirely?

Comment: Any suggestion as to displaying the message only to those users on the older browsers?

Comment: @user1008575 Only IE 8 and below aren't supporting a majority of the CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if ($.browser.msie  && parseInt($.browser.version) <= 8) 
{
     //Your Code
}
```

But i suggest you to not to block IE, So many professionals do use IE.

If you want to block IE, Simply change the HTML content of the page to null after page load.

```
  $('body').html('<span> This site does not support IE8 or below.</span>')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional comments like so.

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
Put your upgrade message here - with any html you like - but no comments
<![endif]-->
```

Only 'seen' by IE
FURTHER INFO: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Answer (score 0):

This could be useful too - http://browser-update.org/

A tiny block of configurable JS that allows you to determine the 'cut off point' for browser support; it then displays a small (non-intrusive, closeable) message at the top of the screen informing the visitor that their current browser will not display all features as intended, and may have security flaws. It offers a link to help them upgrade their current browser.

Rather than block people completely, this feels more helpful, and also a worthwhile 'educational' message! :)